# Editing custom field creates multiple entries in reports and exports with same contact ID

Tags: custom-fields, multiple-records

Civi 5.51.0 wordpress 6.01

Best explained with an image I reckon. Each time I edited this contacts country of birth another entry appears in reports (same with exports from search - multiple rows created).
Doesn't happen if I edit standard fields, only custom fields of any type ie text, date, option,Y/N etc
Making reports and export unuseable HELP
[image]

Comment: What kind of report are you using? Ist it maybe a report based on log entries? Or on activities?

Answer (score 1):

Solved it.
Missing primary key & messed up ID's in civicrm_value table